# how to fill area distance between 2 line in chart echart

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I have a line type eCharts graph and I want to fill the area between the line and the y axis. The default area filling behaviour happens vertically, the chart fills out the space between the line and the x axis. I would like to find an approach on how to draw 2 lines in ECharts and fill up the space between them like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTRNV.png)
These are the options I'm using to set up the chart:

```
let line1 = [
  [42, 1515271.97],
  [41, 1515308.01],
  [40, 1515348.05],
  [50, 1515387.99]
];
let line2 =[
        [39, 1515271.97],
        [40, 1515308.01],
        [42, 1515348.05],
        [45, 1515387.99]
      ]
option = {
  dataZoom: { type: 'inside' },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true,
    transform: {
      type: 'log',
      x: false,
      y: true
    }
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      inverse: true,
      splitLine: { lineStyle: { color: 'grey', opacity: 0.1 } },
      min: 0,
      max: 60
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      inverse: true,
      splitLine: { lineStyle: { color: 'grey', opacity: 0.1 } },
      min: 1515271,
      max: 1515400
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email Line',
      type: 'line',
      data: line1
    },

    {
      name: 'Union Ads Line',
      type: 'line',
      data: line2,
    }
  ]
};
```

I tried 'areaStyle' and 'mark areaStyle' but not as expected
These are the options I'm using to set up the chart use 'areaStyle':

```
option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked Area Chart'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross',
      label: {
        backgroundColor: '#6a7985'
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Email', 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true,
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      splitLine: {
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'grey',
          opacity: 0.1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      splitLine: {
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'grey',
          opacity: 0.1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        opacity: 1,
        origin: "start",
      },
      z: 0,
      data: [[1, 120], [2, 132], [3, 101], [4, 134], [5, 90], [6,230], [7, 210]]
    },
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      areaStyle: {
        color: 'yellow',
        opacity: 1,
        origin: "start",
      },
      z: -1,
      data: [[1, 220], [2, 182], [3,191], [4, 234], [5, 290], [6, 330], [7, 310]]
    },
  ]
};
```

with 'markArea':

```
option = {
  dataZoom: { type: 'inside' },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true,
    transform: {
      type: 'log',
      x: false,
      y: true
    }
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      inverse: true,
      splitLine: { lineStyle: { color: 'grey', opacity: 0.1 } },
      min: 0,
      max: 60
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      inverse: true,
      splitLine: { lineStyle: { color: 'grey', opacity: 0.1 } },
      min: 1515271,
      max: 1515400
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email Line',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        [42, 1515271.97],
        [41, 1515308.01],
        [50, 1515348.05],
        [50, 1515387.99]
      ]
    },

    {
      name: 'Union Ads Line',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        [39, 1515271.97],
        [40, 1515308.01],
        [42, 1515348.05],
        [45, 1515387.99]
      ],
      markArea: {
        silent: true,
        data: [
          [
            {
              xAxis: 50,
              yAxis: 1515271.97
            },
            {
              xAxis: 'max',
              yAxis: 'max'
            }
          ]
        ],
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'yellow',
          opacity: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to fill area horizantolly